# Closure of presentable objects under finite limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

In a locally presentable category $\cal E$, there are arbitrarily large regular cardinals $\lambda$ such that the $\lambda$-presentable (a.k.a. $\lambda$-compact) objects are closed under pullbacks.  Namely, the pullback functor ${\cal E}^{(\to\leftarrow)}\to \cal E$ is a right adjoint, hence accesible.  Thus it preserves $\lambda$-presentable objects for arbitrarily large $\lambda$, so it's enough to check that the $\lambda$-presentable objects in ${\cal E}^{(\to\leftarrow)}$ are those that are pointwise so in $\cal E$.  (A version of this argument is given in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/306129/49) in the case of finite products.)

Of course "arbitrarily large" means that for any cardinal $\mu$ there exists a regular cardinal $\lambda>\mu$ with this property.  A stronger claim would be that this is true for *all sufficiently large* regular cardinals $\lambda$, i.e. to reverse the quantifiers and say there exists a $\mu$ such that all regular cardinals $\lambda>\mu$ have this property (that $\lambda$-presentable objects are closed under pullbacks).  Is this stronger claim true?

Note that it is certainly not true that *all* regular cardinals $\lambda$ have this property; counterexamples can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/189269/49).

Answer (score 10):

The stronger claim is true at least for locally *finitely* presentable categories; this follows from Proposition 4.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.2910.pdf.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you be able to supply a few more details?

Comment: One needs that the pullback functor preserves directed colimits. So, my answer is valid for locally finitely presentable categories only.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense.  That's interesting, but I would really like to know the answer for arbitrary locally presentable categories.

Comment: Pullbacks preserve directed colimits also in localizations of locally finitely presentable categories. But, in general, I would expect a negative answer.

Comment: I would also expect a negative answer in general.  But the first paragraph of the proof of Proposition 6.1.6.7 in *Higher Topos Theory* appears to claim that it is true even for locally presentable $\infty$-categories, although I don't follow the proof (it seems to have a gap precisely at the place where I would expect a sharp cardinal inequality to occur).  So if it does indeed fail in general, it would be nice to have an explicit counterexample.